# GMM adaptation to new data

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, gaussian, pattern-recognition, mixture-model

I have been using the [GMM cluster package](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~bouman/software/cluster/) by Bouman, for which I did not find any adaptation module online. Before I start off reading up on the GMM adaptation theory and implementing it, I did like to know if there are any other opensource GMM projects online which does all of training, testing and adaptation to new data.?

Comment: Ended up implementing MAP adaptation using the equation 9 onwards from this paper https://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/communications/ist/publications/0802_Reynolds_Biometrics-GMM.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer this now but for future reference, I suggest the [Bob](https://pythonhosted.org/bob.bio.gmm/index.html) library (specifically [bob.bio.gmm](https://pythonhosted.org/bob.bio.gmm/_modules/bob/bio/gmm/algorithm/GMM.html)), which provides a wide range of functionalities to manipulate Guassian mixture models for speech related applications including MAP adaptation and UBM generation.